# Get selenium response to manipulate it

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm sorry I expressed a bad idea about what i try to do!
What i try is to to transfer a session from seleniun to Requests, I'm  loggin to a site with selenium and then i need to do some stuff using Requests, and for continue from the login until next step need to get the response from a selenium request and then use it to make a request with Requests library.
These is the idea behind this:
I'm trying to pass a response from a selenium request for example if I do:

```
driver.get(url)
```

then I need to get the response from selenium to do something like:

```
data = self._get_post_type_search(response)
```

I want to manipulate the response, until now I'm reading and looking for useful help but can't find anything to help me.

Comment: If are you open any of the website then you have to put sleep or wait for sometime to get the response and load the content of that particular website and then after you will get the response of the specific website.

Comment: I don't understand. what is the problem? `driver.page_source` ?

Comment: @furas where can i find info about driver.page_source?  anyway, the problem is that a need to manipulate the response before maje another request!

Comment: `driver.page_source` gives page HTML as one string and you need `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` to find elelements.

Comment: BTW try to find more on unoffical page [Selenium with Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or official [Selenium HQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). But I found this in some question or tutorial.

Comment: for some reason, cant answer, well, what i did was copied the cookies from selenium driver and passed them to the request session:

    cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        for cookie in cookies:
            self._session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
        agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
        #end selenium driver
        driver.quit()